# What does the enter key mean in command mode?

Tags: vim

I had up to now always yanked or deleted 2 lines with `y2y` or `d2d`.

I just discover that you can also do `y1CR` (where CR is <kbd>enter</kbd>). Apart from number 1 appear on the command, it actually yanks **two** lines.

It also displays on the bottom `2 lines yanked`, which don't happens using `y2y`.

I can't find any  mention of enter on [vim help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#dd). This lead me to two questions:

1. Is there any other difference except by the extra line when executing those comands using <kbd>enter</kbd>?
2. What <kbd>enter</kbd> was supposed to mean in vim, in a broader sense?

**Edit**: While there are many answers, no one addresses if `y2j` and `y1<CR>` are really equivalent on every case, if they are, why the `2 lines yanked` only appears on bottom only for the `<CR>` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vi commands are a combination of a count, a motion, and an action.  (At least one of the latter two must be present: a motion or action. Otherwise you have a lingering count, waiting for more input.)

`y1CR` means that the count is 1, the motion is "go to the start of the next line", and the action is "yank". "Go to the start of the next line (doing that just once), and yank the lines which are spanned by the motion". Of course, a count of 1 is superfluous.

> With regard to motion and action being combined, you have probably noticed that they do not combine literally; certain combinations follow special rules. For instance the `w` motion goes to the start of the next word, and the `d` action (delete) combines with `dw` in such a way that the word under the cursor, and the space right up the the next word are all deleted. However, the `cw` combination (change word) only deletes the word up to the whitespace which follows, leaving the whitespace. In that case, `c` is not acting on the precise motion carried out by `w` but on an adjusted motion that often makes more sense with `c`.

I cannot reproduce the behavior that `y2j` doesn't print the number of lines yanked. In Vim 7.3 on Ubuntu, `3yy`, `y3y`, `y2CR` and `y2j` all report `3 lines yanked` (if at least 3 lines exist).  All these commands are silent if fewer than 3 lines are yanked. (For instance, they are executed too close to the last line of the buffer, where only two or fewer lines remain, or the repetition counts are reduced to `2yy`, `y2y`, `y1CR` and `y1j` respectively.)

Vim appears to have a three line threshold for reporting this status message. This could have changed between versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - reading the difference of `dw` and `cw` is really worth the upvote (and somewhat sad, because I thought that vim was very orthogonal). I edit the question with two points I expected to see in the answers but it is not. Most likely because my question is faulty. If you can add a comment about that would be really helpful.

Comment: Yes, you are correct with the `x lines yanked` message - my test was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: The 'report' option controls how many lines are affected before the message will show up.

Answer (score 5):

`{count}<CR>` means "go down `{count}` lines".

It's really not that hard to find: see `:help <CR>`.

I tend to prefer `2yy` or `2dd`; it's semantically cleaner and easier to type. From a grammatical perspective, `y2y` sounds weird: "yank two times yank" whereas `2yy` sounds *almost* like plain (yoda) english: "two times yank".

Comment: on the help page it reads `[count] lines downward, on the first non-blank character linewise`. Cool. I just tested and  `y1<CR>` does the same than `y1j`, however in the last one, no `2 lines yanked` appear. Why?

Comment: Do you have evidence that `2yy` is easier to type? I was also surprised by OP's `y2y`. However, if you analyze it, you find that it has the opportunity to be faster. The `2` keystroke can sneak into the recovery time between the two `y`'s.  Basically, `y2y` can take exactly as long to type as just `yy`, whereas `2yy` cannot.

Comment: @Kaz, "easier" and "faster" are two different things.

Comment: @romainl Not really; not in physically executing something with your fingers. For instance, difficult piano passages manifest themselves quite precisely in this way: as tempo bottlenecks.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Enter</kbd> moves from the current line to the following line, so its range covers two lines.

Commands like `y` combined with a movement command are applied to the range of text specified by the movement command. For example, `w` moves from the current position forward to the beginning of the next word, so `yw` yanks all the text in that range.

Similarly, `y`<kbd>Enter</kbd> applies to the two lines covered by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> command -- and since that motion is line-oriented, it applies to the two entire lines, not to some subset of them affected by the starting position.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I edit the question with two points I expected to see in the answers but it is not. Most likely because my question is faulty. If you can add a comment about that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

another way to do that is simply `y<CR>`. and i often actually use things like `yj` or `dk`.